# gspread search for item within list

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I have a Google sheet with lists within the cells.

Ex: A1 contains "1,2,4" and A2 contains "1,5,4,2"

I need to find a way to search if a number is within the list of the cell. I have tried using `worksheet.find(2)` but it returns `None` because it compares the search to the whole cell.

Is there a way to search through the sheet and return cells that contain but do not equal the searched item?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to search the value from a sheet in Google Spreadsheet.
- In your situation, values like `1,2,4` and `1,5,4,2` are put in a cell.
- You want to search for a value of `2` from this situation.

#### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, Sheets API cannot directly search the value from Spreadsheet. So in this case, it is required to use a workaround. In this answer, I would like to propose the following workaround. This workaround retrieves all values from a sheet and searches the value.

#### Sample script:

In this sample script, please use your `worksheet`.

```py
search = 2
values = worksheet.get_all_values()
res = []
for i, r in enumerate(values):
    for j, c in enumerate(r):
        if str(search) in c:
            res.append({'row': i, 'col': j})
print(res)
```

- When this script is run, the row and column indexes of the found cells are returned as a list. When no search value is found, `[]` is returned.

#### Note:

- From `I have tried using worksheet.find(2) but it returns None`, in this case, I thought that an error occurs. Because the argument of `find` for searching is the string type. [Ref](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=find#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.find) So, in this case, it might be `worksheet.find('2')`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure why, but the res printed 1 row and 1 column off from the actual sheet. I converted the columns to letters to easier locate the cells on the google sheet and increased the row and column so they show the correct cell.

Comment: j = chr(ord('@') + j+1) and 
res.append({str(j)+str(i+1)})

Comment: @nikis Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to say. Can I ask you about it? If your issue is still not resolved, I have to apologize.